# Removing items from context menu in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to remove **Show Properties** item from context menu which was added V.7.38 and hold other options in the menu.

Although I'm able to remove older options like *Isolate or Hide selected*, I'm not able to remove **Show Properties** from menu.

```
viewer.registerContextMenuCallback('id', function (menu, st) {
    //remove the item from menu
})
```

This code sample works for older options. Is there any other way to remove newly added options like `Show properties` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a specific menu entry is a bit tricky today, because of these two reasons:

1. Different viewer extensions might register their own menu callback *before* or *after* your callback.
2. When the viewer iterates through all menu callbacks to be executed, it does so simply using `for (const callbackId in viewer.contextMenuCallbacks) { ... }` (where `contextMenuCallbacks` is a JavaScript object), which means that the order of execution is not deterministic.

In case of the "Show properties" menu entry, this one is added by a context menu callback called `propertiesmanager`, added by the built-in viewer extension called `Autodesk.PropertiesManager`. With that said, there are a couple of options to remove the menu entry, for example:

- removing the `propertiesmanager` menu callback using `viewer.unregisterContextMenuCallback('propertiesmanager')`
- trying to register your own menu callback as late as possible to improve the chance that it will be called **after** the `propertiesmanager` callback and that it can therefore remove the "Show properties" during runtime; I was able to achieve this by registering my own menu callback after the `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`, but again, I cannot guarantee that this will always work as the enumeration of object keys (in point 2 above) is not deterministic.
- modifying the behavior of the `Autodesk.PropertiesManager` extension, for example, by modifying its `_onContextMenu` method that handles the menu callback; this is quite hacky though...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Would it be a big compromise to remove context menu callback `propertiesmanager` except that it show properties on right click ? Is there other duties which are done by this callback ?

Comment: From what I've seen, the only thing the `propertiesmanager` callback does is adding the "Show properties" menu item, so you should be fine simply removing the callback.